# Python3 json.dumps gives TypeError: keys must be a string

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I've got a simple web server written in Python3 (using classes from `http.server`) that I'm porting from 2 to 3.

I have the following code:

```
# More code here...
postvars = cgi.parse_qs(self.rfile.read(length),
                        keep_blank_values=1)
something.json_run(json.dumps(postvars))
```

Which throws:

```
TypeError: keys must be a string
```

By inspecting the data, I've determined that `parse_qs` seems to encode the keys as bytes, which is what's throwing the error (`json` doesn't like bytes, apparently).

```
import json
json.dumps({b'Throws error' : [b"Keys must be a string"]})
json.dumps({'Also throws error': [b'TypeError, is not JSON serializable']})
json.dumps({'This works': ['No bytes!']})
```

What is the best solution here? With Python 2, the code works fine because `parse_qs` uses `str` instead of `bytes`. My initial thought is that I probably need to write a JSON serializer. Not that it's difficult for something so simple, but I'd prefer not to if I can do it some other way (e.g. translate the dictionary to using strings instead of bytes).

Comment: `str` in python 2 is the same as `bytes`, actually. the JSON library got more picky in python 3 (with reason).

Comment: So I'm discovering... :P

Comment: See also: http://bit.ly/unipain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, the `cgi.parse_qs` function is deprecated and merely an alias for `urllib.parse.parse_qs`, you may want to adjust your import path.

Secondly, you are passing in a byte string into the parse method. If you pass in a regular (unicode) string instead the `parse_qs` method returns regular strings:

```
>>> from urllib.parse import parse_qs
>>> parse_qs(b'a_byte_string=foobar')
{b'a_byte_string': [b'foobar']}
>>> parse_qs('a_unicode_string=foobar')
{'a_unicode_string': ['foobar']}
```

So you'll need to decode your file-read byte string to a regular string first.